# tf.Print not working if the graph is broken

Tags: python, debugging, tensorflow

I'm trying to build a fully convolutional neural network. My problem is that at some phase the shape of the tensors no longer match, causing and Exception, and I would like to print the shape of the tensors after each step to be able to pin point the problem. However the problem is that the tf.Print does not seem to print anything if the graph is broken and an Exception is thrown at some point (even the exception occurs after the print statement in the pipeline). I'm using the below code in printing. It is working OK if I have a working graph. So is it really that the tf.Print can be used only with working graphs? If this is the case how could I print the shape of tensors or is the only possibility to use some debugger for example tfdbg?

```
upsample = custom_layers.crop_center(input_layer, upsample)
upsample_print = tf.Print(upsample, [tf.shape(upsample)], "shape of tensor is ")
logits = tf.reshape(upsample_print, [-1, 2])
...
```

The error given is

```
ValueError: Dimension size must be evenly divisible by 2898844 but is 2005644 for 'gradients/Reshape_grad/Reshape' (op: 'Reshape') with input shapes: [1002822,2], [4] and with input tensors computed as partial shapes: input[1] = [?,1391,1042,2].
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `print(upsample.get_shape())`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Using regular python print will only print the abstract tensor object during graph creation, not containing the shapes during runtime. I would like to print the actual  tensor shape during the execution of the graph.

Answer (score 0):

`tf.Print` only prints during runtime. It simply adds a node to the graph that upon execution prints something to the console. So, if your graph cannot be constructed, i.e. no computations can be executed, you will never see an output from `tf.Print`.

At construction time, you can only see static shapes of your tensors (and e.g. print them with the Python native print statement). I am not aware of any way to get the dynamic shape at construction time (the dynamic shape is dependent on the actual input you feed, so there is no way of knowing that before you actually feed something, which only happens during runtime). Knowing the static shapes was often enough for my purposes. If it is not the case for you, try to make the dynamic dimensions static in a toy example and then Python-print all the shapes to track down the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not exactly sure what is meant by constructed graph. I think in my case the graph is constructed and executed, but at some point there is a mismatch between shapes and the execution crashed and nothing is printed, even the print statement  is before  line that is causing the crash. If the tf.Print can be used only if a full cycle can be executed, this would imply that the tf.Print is not suitable for debugging for example shape mismatches, but merely to debug working net that is not giving the desired result, which I think should be documented.

Comment: I assumed your crash happens before the graph is deployed in the session. Can you post the actual error?

Comment: I added the error message shown in the bottom of the question @kaufmanu

Comment: I actually managed to find the reason for the given error and now the graph is running fine. However I would still like to know if it is true that the tf.Print cannot be used in the described case or if I'm simply doing something wrong?

Comment: It depends. Shape mismatch errors can happen when you create the graph (for static shapes) or when you actually use the graph for computations (for dynamic shapes). The error you posted does not answer that. Does the error originate from a `sess.run` call? In general the `tf.Print` statement is useful to see what is going on during execution of the computations, so it requires a working graph. But in my experience, the outputs onto the console are not necessarily synchronous.